# Using Anchor Tag To Download File In React

Tags: html, reactjs, prismic.io

i'm trying to use the anchor tag to download a file i have stored in my Prismic.io CMS. However, whenever i click the link, it opens the file as opposed to downloading it. I'm not sure what im doing wrong, heres my code:

note: item.download.url returns a link hosted on aws: https://wroomdev.s3.amazonaws.com/tutoblanktemplate%2F97109f41-140e-4dc9-a2c8-96fb10f14051_star.gif?auto=compress,format

```
<a href={`${item.download.url}`}
   download
>
   <FaDownload
     style={{
       fontSize: "32px",
       marginBottom: "10px",
     }}
   />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need react to achieve this I guess, since you can trigger a download with the HTML5 download attribute. Something like this:

```
<a href={`${item.download.url}`} download="the_file_name">
    <FaDownload
     style={{
       fontSize: "32px",
       marginBottom: "10px",
     }}
   />
   download
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, just tried this out and it still doesnt seem to work. still just opens the file in my browser as opposed to downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be caused by the [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy.

> The same-origin policy is a critical security mechanism that restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It helps isolate potentially malicious documents, reducing possible attack vectors.

The download is controlled by the same-origin.

> download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes

To get through this, you have two options:
1. Access the file by the same origin somehow.
2. Leverage the Blob.